# True/False: If the inhomogeneous system of equations has several possible solutions, the associated homogeneous system does also

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is the following statement true?

> If an inhomogeneous system of linear equations has several possible solutions, then the associated homogeneous system of linear equations also has several solutions.

My initial intuition would be that this is correct, but I can't show it formally. How would one prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: Just subtract the two systems of equations. If $Ax_1=b$ and $Ax_2=b$, with $x_1\neq x_2$, then $A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1-Ax_2=b-b=0$. Therefore, $x_1-x_2$, which is not the zero vector, is a solution of $Ax=0$. So, at least $0$ and $x_1-x_2$ are two solutions of the homogeneous system.

Comment: @yousafe007 If you are asking about a **linear** system of equations, then please make this explicit in your question.